# Simple form notifications does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If leave title field blank i redirecting to `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid at /models` error page instead of show `f.error_notification`.

In my model model_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @model = Model.create(model_params)
  User.add_model(@model)

  if @model.save
    redirect_to(model_path, notice: 'Model was successfully added.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

and in user.rb:

```
def self.add_model(model)
   find_each{ |user| user.models << model }
end
```

And if remove `User.add_model(@model)` then all works as expected. Probably i should add something to `if @model.save` but not sure what exactly.

Comment: In which model you have `title` attribute?

Comment: in model.rb:  `validates :title, presence: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing these lines

`@model = Model.create(model_params)` to `@model = Model.new(model_params)` and

`if @model.save` to `if @model.save!`

And also move `User.add_model(@model)` after `if @model.save!`

Comment: Move `User.add_model(@model) after after `if @model.save` works. Thanks